Animation identification: old man and young man inside a giant machine?
I'm not sure if this is a movie or a TV show, I've spotted it playing a couple of times, but I've never been close enough to hear it, or ask what it is.
I'm pretty sure it's computer animated (with a slight chance it's claymation).
From what I can see, there are two characters:

An older white man (60s). He acts assertively and appears to be guiding the younger man about the space they are in. His behaviour and his dress are all quite eccentric, in a Doctor Who sort of way. He walks with a slight stoop (maybe a hunchback?); has a large bald head (with greying hair on the sides); a white beard (muttonchops?); a square jaw; and a hooked nose. He's wearing a large overcoat that that hangs almost to his knees, without a collar; maybe he's wearing gloves too?
A younger white man (30s). He seems much more timid, and may be awed or intimidated by his surroundings. He's skinnier than the other man, almost gaunt; he has short brown hair; and pale skin. His clothing looks to be a plain white shirt.

The place they're in seems to be some sort of fantastic machine. The only detail I can remember are giant electrical cables crossing the air above them, with sparks jumping out where they meet the walls. At other times, maybe they're crossing a narrow bridge in a huge open space?
That's pretty much everything I can remember. Sorry if it's not much to go on.

The older man you are describing happens to be Nicolas Cage  and the background score of the scene happens to be a song of One Republic ?? If yes I think I got your answer.

It's animated, and any time I saw it I didn't have any audio. So I can't say what the score was, nor if either character sounds like Nick Cage. I don't think either character looks particular like Cage either, though the older one could be said to be gesticulating wildly as the actor is wont to do.

aww.. I had high hopes on The Sorcerer's Apprentice. The scene u described seemed very familiar to this

Wow, apart from not being animated, that's actually really close to what I described. Not it though. What I'm thinking of is much weirder though. Surrealist, even.

Sounds like the Dutch, English-speaking short CGI animation Elephants Dream from 2006.

The two main characters are on a journey in the folds of a giant Machine, exploring the twisted and dark complex of wires, gears and cogs. Until one moment a conflict arises that throws out all their assumptions. This movie short couples lively fun with passionate characters in an epic story line.

Everything you've described regarding the old man, the young man and their surroundings is there, right down to the muttonchops. You can read more about it on Wikipedia. Here's the entire short:



